# MySQL Error - "You have an error in your SQL syntax" on insert

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The error message I'm getting:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO accounts(`balance`, `interest`)
>    VALUES(0, 1.5)' at line 4 in INSERT INTO accounts(`id_user`, `interest`)
>    VALUES(73, 'Savings');
>    INSERT INTO balance(`balance`, `interest`)
>    VALUES(0, 1.5)

My PHP code is:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO accounts(`id_user`, `type`)
          VALUES($userid, '$type');

          INSERT INTO balance(`balance`, `interest`)
          VALUES(0, $interest)";
```

My first guess that something was wrong with my query, so I tried to run the exact same query in phpMyAdmin and it worked perfectly.

Any suggestions on what might be wrong ?

Comment: You are probably using an interface function that only allows a single statement rather than a compound statement.

Comment: I'm using the `mysql_query()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gordon Linoff is correct.

From the great manual in the sky.

"mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier. "

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

change

```
$query = "INSERT INTO accounts(`id_user`, `type`)
          VALUES($userid, '$type');

          INSERT INTO balance(`balance`, `interest`)
          VALUES(0, $interest)";
```

to

```
$query = "INSERT INTO accounts(`id_user`, `type`)
          VALUES($userid, '$type');";
result = mysql_query($query);

$query="INSERT INTO balance(`balance`, `interest`)
          VALUES(0, $interest)";
result = mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using mysqli to run this ? I suspect you are running two queries in a single statement, you need to use **mysqli_multi_query** function to execute multiple queries at the same time.

Mysqli Manual page on [multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)